# Drawing polygons with labeled vertices in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

I'm trying to make basic polygons with graphviz. I have something like this:

```
graph {
    node [shape=circle]
    A [pos="0,1!"]
    B [pos="0,0!"]
    C [pos="1,0!"]
    D [pos="1,1!"]

    A -- B
    B -- C
    C -- D
    D -- A
}
```

which displays the following

[image: polygon1]

I'd like the circles to disappear and look more like this:

[image: polygon2]

I tried switching to `shape=point`, but the labels disappear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `shape=point`, adding a [`xlabel`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:xlabel) to each node will display a label outside of the node shape:

```
A [pos="0,1!", xlabel="A"]
```

The documentation states that the label will be placed outside the node shape, but near the node itself. However, those labels are placed last and can sometimes be omitted ([`forcelabels`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:forcelabels) to the rescue).

The position or an offset can not be defined.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to specify a position offset for the xlabel?

Comment: @yewang I edited the answer with some more detail, but sorry, no position or offset.